# Python bcubed clustering metric- TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'dict' and 'dict'

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, metrics

I want to evalueate my clustering algorithm with bcubed metrics

```
dict_ac = labels_actual.to_dict()
dict_br = pd.DataFrame(labels_br).to_dict()
precision = bcubed.precision(dict_br, dict_ac)
```

But there is error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'dict' and 'dict'
```

Comment: Please include the **full** traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your whole code? The error doesn't seem to be in those three lines.
Also, are you really **sure** that you want to use the "&" operator (according to the error you are using it) which is a **bitwise** operator which means it is used to compare bits to one another.

Did you mean to use the "and" operator?

Example:

```
# example of "&" operator 
byte1 = 0b00001111
byte2 = 0b00100100
byte3 = byte2 & byte1  
# byte3 will be 00000100

# example of the and operator:
if 1=1 and 2=2:
    # do something

# example of using + (adding two strings)
string1 = "Bananas are "
string2 = "yellow!"
string3 = string1 + string2 
# string3 will be "Bananas are yellow!"
```